# How to show recent locations in KFileDialog?

Tags: debian, kde, kde5

In KDE5, unlike how I think it worked previously, the file open dialog opened by e.g. Chrome defaults to a list of recent files. This is really not helpful for me; either I'd like a list of recent locations, or for the dialog to default to the last used location. How can I do this?

I assume the dialog is KFileDialog. I couldn't find anything relevant in the ~/.kde config files, like kdeglobals.

I'm using
Qt: 5.15.2
KDE Frameworks: 5.78.0.